# Let customers add their desired name in each product

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create a custom form on product pages so customers can add their desired names for each product. I want them to be able to search with those names they choose and also edit or delete them in a custom tab on their account dashboard.

I am new in PHP and in Magento and I am trying it for 3 days now without any luck. I tried to copy mage_tag module so I can get its functionality of forms in the product page and in account dashboard but I found out that you cannot search by tags in Magento. I tried to install [Search by tags](https://marketplace.magento.com/dsingh-searchbytags.html) Extension by dharmpal singh but I found out that it doesn’t work.

I am now trying to get it work with Magento core Search Terms (Synonyms) which is near if I can filter them by customer but  then I found out that I can’t add 2 times the same search text for 2 customers.
I think the simplest way is to create a custom product attribute and find a way to change its value for each customer.
Please let me know your thought and a future proof way to build it so I can add in it search/autocomplete/suggestions and API functionality  so I can sync it with an ERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a workaround using Algolia Search Engine with its official Magento Extension. I used Magento Core Tag Functionality (which is officially not an option by Algolia's extension as a searchable attribute). I used [CustomAlgolia extension](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-extend-module-skeleton) to add customer created tag's to algolia's product objects using observer like this:

```
class Vendor_CustomAlgolia_Model_Observer
{
    public function addProductTags($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product_data = $event->getData();
        $customers_skus = array();
        $product_id = $product_data['product']->getId();
        $tag_model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
        $tag_collection = $tag_model
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addPopularity()
            ->addStatusFilter($tag_model->getApprovedStatus())
            ->addProductFilter((int)$product_id)
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->getItems();
        foreach ($tag_collection as $tag) {
            $customers_skus['customer_'.$tag->getData()['first_customer_id'].'_sku'] = $tag->getData()['name'];
        }
        $event->getCustomData()->setData($customers_skus);
    }

}
```

(It check each product if there is any tag added and adds it to Algolia's index with a label like this: customer_2_sku).

[image: added custom attribute to algolia product index]

Then I have to add all those custom created attributes to be searchable in algolia settings.
I used the same observer like this:

```
public function updateProductSettings($observer)
{
    /* Fetching current settings data */
    $settings = $observer->getIndexSettings()->getData();
    /* Getting Tag collection */
    $tag_model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tag_collection = $tag_model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load();
    $tags = $tag_collection->getItems();
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $customer_sku_attribute = 'unordered(customer_'. $tag->getData()['first_customer_id'].'_sku)';
        /* Adding customers with tags to new Algolia settings */
        if(!in_array($customer_sku_attribute, $settings['searchableAttributes'])) {
            array_push($settings['searchableAttributes'], $customer_sku_attribute);
        }
    }
    /* Sending new settings */
    $observer->getIndexSettings()->setData($settings);
}
```

[image: add custom attributes to searchable attributes list]